# display a xml document without the tags?

Tags: php, xml, xsd

i have file called data_out.xml which contains this xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
    - <allproperty>
    - <aproperty>
      <postcode>ha15rs</postcode> 
      <price>250</price> 
      <imagefilename>home2.gif</imagefilename> 
      <visits>2</visits> 
      </aproperty>
    - <aproperty>
      <postcode>ha36gs</postcode> 
      <price>150</price> 
      <imagefilename>home3.gif</imagefilename> 
      <visits>1</visits> 
      </aproperty>
    - <aproperty>
      <postcode>ha27se</postcode> 
      <price>300</price> 
      <imagefilename>home4.gif</imagefilename> 
      <visits>4</visits> 
      </aproperty>
    - <aproperty>
      <postcode>ha4678</postcode> 
      <price>200</price> 
      <imagefilename>home5.gif</imagefilename> 
      <visits>5</visits> 
      </aproperty>
      </allproperty>
```

i want to write a php script that outputs this data without the tags, im not worried about the formatting, just the output, cheers thanks
p.s. im using simplexml

EDIT:

is this wrong or right:

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('data_out.xml', 'r'); 
echo preg_replace('/<[^>]+>/', '', $fp);

?>
```

Comment: sorry i updated the question, SO didint highlight the code, my fault :))

Comment: How do you want it though?  A space between each value?  New line?

Comment: no i just the data to output and not the tags, i dnt care about the formatting just yet!! thanks i dnt really like @slaks answer

Comment: @getaway: fopen() does not return the contents of the file.  You need to use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file-get-contents) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually a built in [PHP function for stripping tags](http://php.net/strip_tags) called...`strip_tags()`.

```
echo strip_tags($xml_string);
```

No need to remember the regex!

EDIT: Just for posterity, here's the output for your sample XML http://ideone.com/hQS4P

Comment: +1, tested and does work (to my surprise).  Didn't know it worked on non-HTML tags.

Comment: @Jonah Bron I actually trust it more with XML than with HTML, since (valid) XML (at least in theory) is always well-formed, whereas its much harder to predict with HTML whether all the tags will be properly formed.

Answer (score 2):

This is massive overkill for what you're trying to do right now, but if you want to enhance it to format your data more nicely later, you may want to consider XSLT.  This produces what you are looking for right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:variable name="clean" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($clean) > 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="$clean"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How do I implement this? Where do I put the XML code? Is this supposed to be a PHP file?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to strip all tags, and *if* the XML is fully valid, you can use a regex.

Replace `<[^>]+>` with `''`.

If the XML might have `>` characters in attributes, this won't work; you'd need a more complicated regex which is aware of strings.

**EDIT**: For example:

```
echo preg_replace('/<[^>]+>/', '', $someXML);
```

Comment: You may also want to run this on it, too: `preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $someXML );`.  Otherwise, you're going to have a boatload of spaces and new lines.

Comment: i updated my answer, that script is not working, is thier something i need to add, sorry i know im a pain in the ass!!!